# Is there any way to change the color of a text using send_keys in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, colors

I have a script (a web-scraper) in python --also using `selenium`-- and at some point I have to fill some field. After I fill it I attach a random paragraph with `lorem` module. The point is that I want to hide this paragraph, for example, giving it some transparency or changing the color to white (cause the background is white).

My code is something like this:

```
# import selenium, lorem, create the webdriver object,
# get the url, etc.
driver.find_element_by_id('some_id').send_keys(
        'some_string' + lorem.paragraph())
```

So, is there any way to change the color (or make it transparent) to the second string `lorem.paragraph()` without affecting the legibility of the first one?

I am new to python selenium and would appreciate if someone could help with that. Thanks in advance. Any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you do this manually in browser without using other tools like DevTool ? If you can't then Selenium also can't do this. You could use JavaScript in your script to change HTML elements but after reloading it will remove your changes. And this changes will exist only in your browser - other users will not see these changes.

Comment: Yeap, absolutely that's a good point in order to know first if it's possible. I don't know right now if I can do it, actually. I will try and see. Thanks

Comment: if there is no place to write color number or button change it then Selenium can't change it. If you need to change color only for you then you can install browser extension [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) and you can customize style on page. But it is only for you. Other peole will not see these changes.

Comment: Until now I think I can´t do it. I mean, I can of course change the style but just of the whole text, so I can´t parcel the style. Unfortunately I need to make changes not for me, but thanks for let me know about Stylish --sincerely I didn´t know about it.

Comment: if form on page doesn't have function to change color then you can't change it.

Comment: if form accepts HTML code then you could put `<div color="white">some string</div>` or something similar with `<div style="...">`

Comment: `<div>` didn't work, or `<p>` or `<span>`, just `<h1>`. I really don't know why. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function to attach HTML markup to your text.
Something like:

```
def hide(text): 
  return '<h1 style="color:white">' + text + '</h1>'
```

An then use it to whiteup your text

```
# import selenium, lorem, create the webdriver object,
# get the url, etc.
driver.find_element_by_id('some_id').send_keys(
        'some_string' + hide(lorem.paragraph()))
```